# Fancybox doesn't load div

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So I am writing a code to load a div in a fancybox, but instead the hole page is loaded in the box instead of the specified div. Code as follows

```
<a href="#remindme" id="remindmelink">Remind me</a>

<div id="remindme" style="display:none;">
<form action="tbd">
    <label for="remind_me_email" class="required"><em>*</em>E-Mail Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="remind_me_email" class="input-text-pop" title="E-Mail Address" />
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="remind_me_submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#remindmelink").fancybox({
'href': '#remindme'
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I solved it! The solution is like this
    <div style="display:none;">
    <div id="remindme">
    <form> <!...> </form>
    </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. Make sure you are loading Fancybox Javascript.

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/87M2N/)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#remindmelink").fancybox({
'href': '#remindme'
});
});
```

Comment: It is loaded in the main page! the fancybox opens but it load complete page not just the specified div